# Can I use a command to display/announce the time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to be able to say the current time in game.  Is this possible?  I have tried things like `/say &t`, `/say @t`, etc. I would just like to announce the current time.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this on the fly, or is an automatic command block system an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/time query daytime` should work

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible without the use of mods. The only commands that can do anything related with time are `/time`, and `/gamerule doDaylightCycle`. The first changes the time, but does not list what it currently is, and the second turns the passage of time off or on.

The only way to tell time in un-modded Minecraft is the use of the [clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock) item. Notably, clocks still work while mounted inside an [item frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_frame), allowing you to place one on the wall somewhere prominent if you wish to tell the time frequently without using up an inventory space.